# TPersistent component in a TCollectionItem / Access a TCollectionItem property from a TPersistent

Tags: delphi, tpersistent, tcollectionitem

Please take a look to the bellow code part of a `TComponent`:

```
TMyField = class(TCollectionItem)
private
  FName: String
  FSqlField: TSqlField;
  procedure SetName(const Value: String);
  procedure SetSqlField(const Value: TSqlField)
published
  property Name: String read FName write SetName;
  property SqlField: TSqlField read FSqlField write SetSqlField;
end;  

TSqlField = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FAlias: String;
    FName: String;
    FTable: String;
    procedure SetField(Index: Integer; Value: String);
  public
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property Alias: String index 0 read FAlias write SetField;
    property Name: String index 1 read FName write SetField;
    property Table: String index 2 read FTable write SetField;
  end;

procedure TSqlField.SetField(Index: Integer; Value: String);
var
  FOwner: TMyField;
begin
  if (Value <> FAlias) or (Value <> FName) or (Value <> FTable) then
    begin
      case Index of
        0: if Value <> FAlias then FAlias:= Value;
        1: if Value <> FName then FName:= Value;
        2: if Value <> FTable then FTable:= Value;
      end;

      if FName <> '' then
        begin
          FOwner:= GetOwner; //Error here: E2010 Incompatible types: 'TMyField' and 'TPersistent'
          if FTable <> '' then FOwner.Name:= Format('%s_%s',[FTable,FName])
          else FOwner.Name:= FName;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

When the method `SetField` from `TSqlField` is processed I would like to access the property `Name` from `TSqlField : TCollectionItem` so I can rename it.

Remark: The owner of `TCollection` could be one or another `TComponent`.

Please some suggestions about how can this be done.

Comment: Typecast `GetOwner as TMyField`.

Comment: @Victoria: that will not work in the code shown. `TSqlField` derives directly from `TPersistent` and does not override the virtual `GetOwner()` method. `TPersistent.GetOwner()` returns nil by default.  In its current form, `TSqlField` has no linkage to the `TMyField` that owns it. `TMyField` needs to pass its `Self` pointer to `TSqlField` so `TSqlField` can store it in a private member and return it from an overridden `GetOwner()`.

Comment: @Remy, now I see. I must have been full of collections here. I understand how it should work, but thanks :)